# Referring to a field in a numpy structured array is the same size as the entire array

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

### Issue

I have a numpy structured array and I want to take two small fields. When I do, I get an item that is as large as the original

### Example

```
>>> A = np.zeros(100, dtype=[('f',float),('x',float,2),('large',float,500000)])
>>> A.itemsize
4000024
>>> A['f'].itemsize
8
>>> A['x'].itemsize
8
>>> A[['x','f']].itemsize
4000024
>>> A[['x']].itemsize
4000024
```

### Question

Why does taking a slice of fields in a numpy array produce an array that is as large as the original? (I'm using python3.8 and numpy version 1.18.3)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _size_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numpy function that is needed is [repack_fields](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#numpy.lib.recfunctions.repack_fields). The example then becomes:

```
>>> from numpy.lib.recfunctions import repack_fields
>>> A = np.zeros(100, dtype=[('f',float),('x',float,2),('large',float,500000)])
>>> A[['x']].itemsize
4000024
>>> repack_fields(A[['x']]).itemsize
16
```

Note that repacking the fields of `A` will necessarily use more memory. This may be desired, for example when using mpi4py to communicate `A[['x']]` between ranks (and all of `A` is too large to communicate).

Comment: Yes, this uses more memory. I now note this, and provide a use case where it is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Make an array that's small enough to actually display:

```
In [151]: A = np.zeros(3, dtype=[('f',float),('x',float,2),('large',float,10)])
In [152]: A
Out[152]: 
array([(0., [0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
       (0., [0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
       (0., [0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
      dtype=[('f', '<f8'), ('x', '<f8', (2,)), ('large', '<f8', (10,))])
```

Select one field:

```
In [153]: A['f']
Out[153]: array([0., 0., 0.])
```

Select a list of fields:

```
In [154]: A[['f']]
Out[154]: 
array([(0.,), (0.,), (0.,)],
      dtype={'names':['f'], 'formats':['<f8'], 'offsets':[0], 'itemsize':104})
```

As of something like version 1.17, indexing with a list of fields returns a `view`.  Thus `itemsize` is the same as the original.

```
In [155]: A.itemsize
Out[155]: 104
In [156]: A[['x']].itemsize
Out[156]: 104
```

The difference between indexing with a list versus a field name may be clearer when looking at the last field.  One is still a structured array, the other is a 2d array.

```
In [159]: A[['large']].dtype
Out[159]: dtype({'names':['large'], 'formats':[('<f8', (10,))], 'offsets':[24], 'itemsize':104})

In [160]: A[['large']].shape
Out[160]: (3,)
In [161]: A['large'].shape
Out[161]: (3, 10)
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#accessing-multiple-fields

> Note that unlike for single-field indexing, the dtype of the view has **the same itemsize** as the original array, and has fields at the same offsets as in the original array, and unindexed fields are merely missing.